# How to calculate average of adjacent rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping, mean, rolling-computation

I got a DF with peoples salary data and their job. One row is one person. I need to calculate the average salary of 3 people on the same job and make a new DF out of it. The 3 people need to be on the same job and their wages need to be adjacent if the DF is sorted from highest to lowest salary. The average salary of the person themselves and the ones above and below them in the DF if they have the same job. The people with the highest and lowest salary in a job are excluded as they have nobody above or below them.

This is a sample of the data i have

```
Job     salary
IT       5000
IT       4500
IT       4000
IT       4000
Sales    4500
Sales    4500
Sales    4000
Sales    3000
Sales    2500
HR       3000
HR       2500
HR       2300
```

This is what i would like to get (if the average salary went to decimal places i rounded it. But in the R DF there is no need to do it. Decimal places are ok.

```
Job    salary
IT      4500
IT      4167
Sales   4333
Sales   3833
Sales   3167
HR      2600
```

I'm stuck as i can't figure out how to calculate the average of the 3 people on the same job and exclude the top and bottom. Hope you can help.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a rolling average by group. This can be done with `zoo::rollmean` coupled with `dplyr::group_by`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

dat %>% 
  group_by(Job) %>% 
  summarise(mean = rollmean(salary, 3, align = "right"))

  Job    mean
  <fct> <dbl>
1 IT    4500 
2 IT    4167.
3 Sales 4333.
4 Sales 3833.
5 Sales 3167.
6 HR    2600
```

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what i was looking for. That does the (align = "right") do?

Comment: It forces the rolling average to be done with the n values **after** the current value. (other option are center and left).

Comment: Note that rollmeanr with r on the end defaults to align = "right".

Answer (score 1):

Here are some base R options

```
> with(df,stack(tapply(salary, Job, function(x) rowMeans(embed(x, 3)))))
    values   ind
1 2600.000    HR
2 4500.000    IT
3 4166.667    IT
4 4333.333 Sales
5 3833.333 Sales
6 3166.667 Sales

> aggregate(salary ~ ., df, function(x) rowMeans(embed(x, 3)))
    Job                       salary
1    HR                         2600
2    IT           4500.000, 4166.667
3 Sales 4333.333, 3833.333, 3166.667
```